# Bad diff between mysql datetime and now datetime object

Tags: php, mysql, datetime

I want to get time between dates in secounds and here is my code:

```
$rezultat = $polaczenie->query(sprintf("SELECT terminstart FROM uzytkownicy WHERE id=%d", $_SESSION['id']));
$wiersz = $rezultat->fetch_assoc();

$start = DateTime::createFromFormat('Y-m-d H:i:s', $wiersz['terminstart'])->format('Y-m-d H:i:s');
echo'<script>alert("'.$start.'");</script>';

$teraz = (new \DateTime())->format('Y-m-d H:i:s');
echo'<script>alert("'.$teraz.'");</script>';

$interval = $start->diff($teraz);
echo'<script>alert("'.$interval.'");</script>';
```

I see from alerts, that $start is working good, $teraz (means now) is working good but I even don't get 3th error with diff. What is the problem?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`$start` and `$teraz` are strings, not `DateTime` objects because you call `DateTime::format()` on them. You can only do a diff on `DateTime` objects.

```
$start = new DateTime($wiersz['terminstart']);
$teraz = new \DateTime();
$interval = $start->diff($teraz);
```

Also:

1. Don't use javascript for debugging. That's kinda insane.
2. You don't need `DateTime::createFromFormat()` if you date is already in an acceptable format (and Y-m-d H:i:s is an acceptable format)

Comment: Oh thats a relief, was just about to ping you for a comment answer. How are you

Comment: I'm doing well. How are things on your end?

Comment: Thanks foryour helpbut I still have problem with that diff. i made new post with actual code. Please for help.

Comment: Make sure `$wiersz['terminstart']` has a value and it is a value you are expecting

Comment: I am 100% sure that that variable has that value: "2016-07-28 00:00:00" and its not text in database its "DATATIME" format.

Comment: Ok I am happy that this is working to you but can you tell me what can be aproblem if it is still not working? Maybe PHP version? I really don't know its very iritating situation when code is good but still dont work.

Comment: What version of PHP are you using? This should work with PHP 5.3 or newer

Comment: I am using 5.6.24 Now I have simple test and it doesnt work. I see only first alert:
  $teraz = new DateTime("now");
  echo '<script>alert("aha");</script>';
  echo '<script>alert("'.$teraz.'");</script>';

Comment: `DateTime` is an object, not a string. You can't echo it out.

Comment: OK that was bad example but diff is a number yes? Number of  secounds in int? I cant see it too.  $teraz = new DateTime("now");
  $start = new DateTime($wiersz['terminstart']);
  $interval = $start->diff($teraz);
  echo'<script>alert("'.$interval.'");</script>';

Comment: Diff returns a [`DateInterval`](http://php.net/manual/en/class.dateinterval.php) *object*, not a string or number.

Comment: Oh my god... how can I format it to secounds? I tried to use $interval -> format('s'); but it doesn't work.

Comment: Your idea doesnt work. Finally, that code saved me:
$interval = $teraz->getTimestamp() - $start->getTimestamp(); Thanks for  help andyou are getting best answer check.